# How can I enumerate all managed threads in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it possible to enumerate all managed threads in C#? Visual Studio seems to be able to do this when you hit a break point while debugging. In the "Threads" window it shows a list of all running threads, including managed names. Does anyone know how it does this?

Comment: @Marc: I thought there must be a different way, as VS can enumerate them. I might end up tracking them myself though.

Comment: @Marc, I disagree. Maybe he's working on an IDE and wants to include debugging capabilities. "Keep track of your own threads" is not a valid answer in this case. The question could be marked as duplicate, but the "short answer" is not the best one.

Comment: @Hosam Aly: OK, I'll accept that... I'll rollback and re-post as a reply

Comment: See an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315862/get-list-of-threads/35558240#35558240

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debuggers are often able to do things "normal" code can't. You'd probably find that you can do this if you use the profiling/debugging API, but I don't believe you can do it from "normal" .NET code.

Comment: I don't see how to do it from a debugger either. It appears that the thread ids given in the debugger are the Win32 ids rather than the managed thread ids.

Comment: @CrazyCasta: I'm not saying you can explicitly do it *from* a debugger. I'm saying that when the debugger *does* list all threads, it can use APIs which aren't available elsewhere. Even if it lists Win32 *ids*, it still shows managed thread *names*, doesn't it?

Comment: I see what appear to be managed names, however there's a few problems. 1. It could be that the managed code is just setting the name of the unmanaged thread. 2. As has been stated, there is no defined 1:1 correlation between unmanaged and managed threads. Each unmanaged thread could be switching between two managed threads. 3. I would guess that the debugger is just enumerating unmanaged threads.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a duplicate of "[How to enumerate threads in .NET using the Name property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427485/how-to-enumerate-threads-in-net-using-the-name-property)" - If so, the short answer is "keep track of your own threads yourself" - i.e. in a `List<Thread>` or similar.

Comment: This is what I may end up doing, I was just hoping there was already something doing it for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Managed Stack Explorer](http://mse.codeplex.com/):

> MSE works by quickly attaching to a
>   process when a stack trace is
>   requested and the detaching the second
>   the stack trace has been retrieved.
>   This way the interference in the
>   normal operation of the process is
>   minimized.

Unfortunately, this means it **has** to done by an external process.

A similar tool is [StackDump](http://stackdump.codeplex.com/), which uses [MDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861.aspx) to generate the dump.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate threads by making an HTTP GET request to [ProcInsp](https://github.com/CUSTIS-public/ProcInsp). ProcInsp allows you to get threads with stack traces of CLR processes (either in its UI or as a JSON message). The web API is available at `/Process/%PID%/Threads`.

Disclaimer: I am the developer of this tool. It is MIT-licensed and free for use.